# May I run regression models in coral Edge TPU?

Tags: google-coral

Would I be able to use Coral products for addressing regression problems (models predicting some numbers given a set of numbers)? I see predominantly either classification or object detection problems are demonstrated. Thanks.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it did answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to run regression network using `BasicEngine`. `ClassificationEngine` and `DetectionEngine` are just a wrapper around `BasicEngine`.